# Trace of derivative of metric?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not quite sure what happens when I take the trace of a partial derivative of a metric tensor. Furthermore I have that

\begin{equation}
\gamma_{\mu \nu} = \partial_x g_{\mu \nu}(x).
\end{equation}

Now if I take the trace, do I get
\begin{equation}
\text{Tr}(\partial_x g_{\mu \nu}(x))=(\partial_x g_{\mu \nu}(x))(\partial_x g^{\mu \nu}(x))
\end{equation}
or can the derivative be taken out so that I simply get

\begin{equation}
\text{Tr}(\partial_x g_{\mu \nu}(x))=(\partial_x g_{\mu \nu}(x))( g^{\mu \nu}(x))
\end{equation}

On the one hand I know that technically I can raise the index of $\partial_x g_{\mu \nu}(x)$ with simply $g^{\mu \nu}$.

But on the other hand it is also true that $\gamma_\mu^\mu =\gamma_{\mu \nu} \gamma^{\mu \nu}$ suggests that the first option is right.

If someone just gave me a metric, say $h_{\mu \nu}(x)$, I would tell them that the trace is  $h_{\mu \nu} h^{\mu \nu}$. But what if this metric can be written as the derivative of another metric, say $p(x) = d_x h_{\mu \nu}(x)$ where all the metric elements being the anti-derivative of the original metric? Then the definition of the trace would change?

Clearly I am missing something.

Comment: the $x$ in $\partial_x$ shouldn't be the $x$ in $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$, to start

Comment: Consider e.g. $\text{diag}(x^2, x^3)=\partial_x \text{diag}(\frac{x^3}{3}, \frac{x^4}{4})$. Why would the $x$ not be the same?

Comment: Ok, then $\partial_x=\dfrac{d}{dx}$, that is, there aren't several variables

Comment: Yes, sorry. But they are partial in my example, I did not write other variables, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Let us suppose that
$g_{ij}=g_{ij}(x,y)$
then for $\partial_xg_{ij}$ and $\partial_yg_{ij}$ we have the matrices
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\partial_xg_{11}&\partial_xg_{12}\\
\partial_xg_{21}&\partial_xg_{22}
\end{array}\right)\qquad,\qquad
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\partial_yg_{11}&\partial_yg_{12}\\
\partial_yg_{21}&\partial_yg_{22}
\end{array}\right),$$
from, you can see the traces.

In the other hand having $g_{is}g^{sj}=\delta_i{}^j$, here with $s$-sum, then one can use Leibniz' rule to get
$$0=(\partial_xg_{is})g^{sj}+g_{is}(\partial_xg^{sj}).$$

Then you could deduce how is $\partial_xg^{ij}$ in terms of $g^{ij}$ and $\partial_xg_{ij}$, similar for $\partial_yg^{ij}$.